# Edit Class, add or remove "int" according to what's in the datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datatable

I have a table in a database and to update it, I use the class to hold all the information to process.

What I would like to do is:

1. Read from the database, into a datatable.
2. Check if the class contains all the fields in the datatable
3. If it does then fine. If it doesn't then I would like to add those fields to the class. If the class contains fields the datatable does not, I want to remove them.

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stock_A_Lot.DAL.Classes
{
    public class Report
    {
        public int ReportID { get; set; }
        public DateTime RepDate { get; set; }
        public int RepPSold { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the form Code:

```
using Stock_A_Lot.BAL;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stock_A_Lot.PL
{
    public partial class Report_Form : Form
    {
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
        Database_Handler dbh = new Database_Handler();
        public Report_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Report_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable Prods;
            String query = "Select ProdDesc From Product";
            Prods = db.GetDataTable(query);

            DataTable Report;
            String queryReport = "Select * From Report";
            Report = db.GetDataTable(queryReport);

            foreach (DataRow dr in Prods.Rows)
            {
                ContainColumn(dr[0].ToString() + "Curr", Report);
                ContainColumn(dr[0].ToString() + "Prev", Report);
                //Check class here if possible
            }
        }
        private void ContainColumn(string columnName, DataTable table)
        {
            DataColumnCollection columns = table.Columns;

            if (columns.Contains(columnName))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                string query = "ALTER TABLE Report ADD COLUMN \"" +columnName + "\"  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';";
            dbh.updatereportable(query);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you planning on using those fields in code if they are runtime dependent? Are you just trying to keep the class synced with the db or are you really after dynamic runtime class generation? if its the latter you could use reflection and/or Roslyn but its not a trivial task at all.

Comment: @PaulSwetz The table is always going to be changing, so I want to have the class synced with the table, but i have thought about it how will i put the info in the class fields if i don't know what fields are going to be there when the user clicks the button to add the information to the db. The other way i thought of is just to pass an array with all the information to the method that does the inserting, What do you think about that?

Comment: You want an ORM framework like Entity Framework then, don't try and do it yourself. That or just work with the datatable/datasets.

Comment: @PaulSwetz I'm going to take a look at that, never heard of it before so will take a look, Thanx for the advice :)

Comment: Entity Framework will change your life.